# Homology and fundamental group of a cylinder with bottom being identified by the relation $z^n=w^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, homology-cohomology, fundamental-groups, cw-complexes

This is a problem from my past Qual

"Let $m,n$ be positive integers and view $S^1$ as the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $X$ be the space obtained from the cylinder $S^1\times [0,1]$ by identifying $(z,0)$ and $(w,0)$ if $z^n=w^n$ and identifying $(z,1)$ and $(w,1)$ if $z^m=w^m$.

(a) Use Mayer-Vietoris to compute $H_i(X)$.

(b) Use Seifert-van Kampen to find $\pi_1(X)$."

My solution: (a) Naturally, let $A$ be the upper-half of the cylinder and $B$ be the lower-half (Of course we enlarge it more than a half for them to cover $X$). THen $A\cap B$ deformation retracts to $S^1$. $A$ and $B$ deformation retract to their top and bottom.

**I GUESS**  that the top of $A$ is formed by one $0$-cell, one $1$-cell and one $2$-cell that attaches to the $1$-skeleton by the map $z\mapsto z^m$. Again, this is a guess, it's hard to imagine. With this the chain complex of $A$ is
$$0\to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{m} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$
and hence $H_2(A)=0,H_1(A)=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and $H_0(A)=\mathbb{Z}$.

(b) About fundamental group, if I'm right, then $\pi_1(A)=\langle a|a^m \rangle = \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. I'm not good at visualizing, but **I GUESS** that the induced map $\pi_1(A\cap B) \to \pi_1(A) $ is given by projection $1\mapsto 1$. Hence $\pi_1(X)=\langle a,b|a^m,b^n, ab^{-1} \rangle = \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$ where $d=gcd(m,n)$.

My questions: 1) Is my part (a) correct so far? I don't want to continue before knowing if it's true or not.

2. Is my part (b) correct? Is there a way to visualize the induced map in this case?

Comment: It seems to me that the top of $A$ and the bottom of $B$ are each just a circle. The nontrivial topology comes from the way the circle at the middle (the deformation retract of $A\cap B$) lines up with the top and bottom circles when you push it up or down along the cylinder. It will wind $m$ times around the top and $n$ times around the bottom..

Comment: Not quite. If you let $a$ be the generator for the top, and $b$ be the generator for the bottom, then note that $a^m$ is homotopic to the generator of the intersection, and similarly $b^n$ as well. So really you have $\pi_1(X) = \langle a, b | a^mb^{-n} \rangle$. This matches with the intuition that @AndreasBlass provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, notice that $z \to z^m$ and $z \to z^n$ are covering maps so really you still end up with a circle on the top and bottom. Thus, $\pi_1(A) = \langle a \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z} \cong \langle b \rangle = \pi_1(B)$. Now, as you pointed out, $A \cap B \cong S^1$ so $\pi_1(A \cap B) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Let's see where this generator goes. If you push it "up" into the $A$ component, then it winds around $m$ times due to the way the quotienting worked, and similarly pushing it "down" into the $B$ component, it winds around $n$ times. So we have that $a^m = b^n$ or that $a^mb^{-n}$ is a relation. So $\pi_1(X) \cong \langle a,b | a^mb^{-n} \rangle$.

Before continuing with Mayer-Vietoris, it might be helpful to think about what we should expect. $H_1(X)$ is the abelianization of $\pi_1(X)$, so we should expect something like $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ where $ma = nb$ i.e. $\mathbb{Z}/(\gcd (m,n))$

We have the sequence
$$0 \to H_2(A \cap B) \to H_2(A) \oplus H_2(B) \to H_2(X) \to H_1(A \cap B) \to H_1(A) \oplus H_1(B) \to H_1(X) \to 0$$
Note that we don't have to include the $H_0$ because all the pieces are path connected (this is equivalent to doing the calculation with reduced homology). Filling some pieces in, we have
$$0 \to 0 \to 0 \to H_2(X) \to H_1(A \cap B) \to H_1(A) \oplus H_1(B) \to H_1(X) \to 0$$
Note that the map $H_1(A \cap B) \to H_1(A) \oplus H_1(B)$ is injective (it is the map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ given by $1 \mapsto (m,n)$), so in fact we just deal with the short exact sequence
$$0 \to H_1(A \cap B) \to H_1(A) \oplus H_1(B) \to H_1(X) \to 0$$
Now, we have
$$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{(\times m, \times n)} \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \to H_1(X) \to 0$$
So $H_1(X) \cong (\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z})$ modulo the relation $ma = nb$ so we have $H_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}/(\gcd(m,n))$, which is precisely what we expected.

**Edit: Understanding the Quotient**

Alright so first let us understand what it means when saying $z^n = w^n$. In $S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}$, points are of the form $e^{i\theta}$. Thus we identify points if $e^{in\theta_1} = e^{in\theta_2}$. When would this occur? When $n\theta_1-n\theta_2 = 2k\pi$ or when $\theta_1 - \theta_2 = \frac{2k\pi}{n}$. Thus, what is being done is that $S^1$ is being cut into $n$ equal parts and those parts are being identified, so you are essentially gluing by the map $z \mapsto z^n$ as you pointed out. So the quotient is just one of these parts (arcs) with endpoints identified so is just $S^1$ again. If you're comfortable with covering spaces, you'll recall that $S^1$ is a finite covering of itself. This is a manifestation of that fact. It's the same idea as $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} = S^1$ (indeed $\mathbb{R}$ is the universal cover).

So, the correct way to visualize the cylinder is as a regular cylinder with the top twisted up $m$ times and the bottom twisted up $n$ times.

Comment: we identify a lot of points on the top and the bottom but they are still homotopy equivalent to circles?

Comment: Yes! Let me add a section above that might help explain why.

Comment: thank you. This is the part I hate the most about AT. Sometimes you misunderstand but you don't know you do

Comment: That comment sounded familiar so I realized I answered one of your previous questions too haha. I hope you grow to enjoy AT! It truly is my favourite field out there.

Comment: thanks. I like learning it too but it's so hard understanding it :))